# Is 'identity' an optional characteristic for real world objects?

Tags: oop

Somewhere I've read

1. **An object has three characteristics**:

   - state (e.g. name)
   - behavior (e.g. reading)
   - identity(unique id number of student)

As per this information, every object will have unique identification, so that all objects of a class will be different from each other.

but,

2. In many other places I've read that **objects have two characteristics**:

   - state
   - behavior

### Question:

which one is true? objects have 2 characteristics or 3 characteristics?

suppose there are two erasers of the same brand, look, shape, size and color.

So, these two objects should be treated as **'equal objects'** as there is nothing to uniquely identify them?

Comment: this is no specific java question! it's merely about OOP!

Comment: great question. don't pay attention to down voters

Comment: Define "unique". We're both human so we're the same. We're also both less than 100 years old, so we're the same. But your name is "java_beginner" while mine is "Jeroen". Are we still the same? Or does it depend on what you arbitrarily decide defines uniqueness?

Comment: It is a valid beginner question imo. It demonstrates curiosity, a key attribute for any successful programmer. The tags should be changed though.

Comment: "same brand,same look,shape,size and color" =>  are generally value objects.

Answer (score 3):

### *Explicit* identity is optional.

However, the culmination of an object's states and behaviors is an ***implicit* identity**; thus,

### *Implicit* identity is required.

Two objects can have the exact same ***intrinsic*** characteristics (eg. color, size, shape), but differ in their ***extrinsic*** characteristics (eg. location, owner).

In this way, two objects may be considered *equivalent* when compared by a selection of their properties, but would be considered *distinct* in terms of the culmination of all intrisic or extrinsic states and behaviors.

Answer (score 2):

**Value Objects** (for instance date, color, etc..) haven't by essence the notion of identity.
Two distinct `Color` objects **MAY** be equal as long as their properties (values) are equal (checked by HashCode/equals).
It is quite possible that your design leads you to define `Color` as an **Entity** but in a very few cases.

In the contrary, each **entity** (user123, car456 etc..) owns a unique id, and comparison are usually made through this id. `HashCode/equals` only take account of the id.

So if I want to make a rule for both, it would be:

**object has two characteristics: state and behavior**

Answer (score 2):

In your provided analogy, you bring up two identical erasers with the same characteristics. If you show them to us, and ask us, are they different, we will say "No. They are the same."

However, if you were to ask us if these two erasers are actually the same singular eraser, we'd wonder how we got to Philosophy SE.

Identity does not have to be explicitly defined. Take the case of `String` for example.

If I do:

```
String a = "ABCDE";
String b = "ABCDEFG".substring(0, 5); //turns into ABCDE
```

We have two Strings storing identical information ABCDE

We can do two comparisons:

```
a == b //false
a.equals(b) //true
```

These two Strings are like your two erasers. They are equal in that they both consist of ABCDE, but they aren't actually the same singular String, but two separate sets of characters that are coincidentally the same thing.

Both a and b point to a unique reference to "ABCDE". In this case, we don't have an explicit identity, but both a and b are unique references, so the language knows, "Hey, these are two different Strings."

Now, let's return to the eraser example. In this case, we haven't been provided any sort of way to differentiate the two, but we can still differentiate the two.

One eraser is on the left, one is on the right (or however they're arranged)

These erasers have implicitly, by us, been given an identity so we recognize that they're two different erasers with identical properties.

We can explicitly define an identity by giving erasers serial numbers or names. They may look the same, but they now have explicit identities rather than the ones we have made up in our head.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that you can regard Identity as being part of State... The vast majority of classes will have some form of identity stored with them, but it's not a hard and fast rule. Consider, for instance, strings...

Out in the real world though, the vast majority of what you do will involve talking to databases, and joining information together. Keys are crucial to that, and your identity is basically your key... In the old days just because it was in your database didn't mean you would have it in your class, but in this era of Object Relational Mappers I'd get used to the idea if I were you...

Answer (score 1):

If two objects are completely the same in *every* way, there's no way to distinguish between them, so they're the same object.  Distinct objects — those that are *not* the same object — are distinct because they differ in some way.  Your two erasers may have the same brand, look, shape, size, and color, but they differ in their position:  they don't physically overlap in space.  You can put them on the table next to each other and see them in their distinct locations, so you know they're distinct objects.

You may find it useful to consider two distinct objects *equivalent* even if they differ in some of their properties — two erasers in different physical locations but the same in other characteristics, or two data structures at different memory addresses but containing the same data.  This is the difference between Java's `equals()` method and its `==` operator.

Answer (score 1):

You are describing the difference between Reference Equality (literally the same object) and Value Equality (have the same properties). Whether or not a given object should have Reference Equality or Value Equality is NOT dependent solely on the object itself; it depends on the context. In most contexts, a dollar bill has value equality: one is just as good as another, we interchange them freely, and we don't care at all about the "identity" of each individual bill. However, to a counterfeit specialist working for the treasury department, all dollar bills are not the same, and the identity of the individual bill matters a lot.

Another example might be an airplane. If I am getting on an American Airlines flight, whether or not the airplane is a 737 or an S80 matters to me: one has 6 seats in a row while the other has 5, one has AC power in every seat while the other does not. But I only care about the properties of the plane, not the identity; one 737 is just as good as another to me. But to the mechanics who maintain the planes, the identity matters a great deal. One plane has just been serviced, while another is approaching its service deadline; keeping track of which one is which is extremely important.

So before you decide how to model your object, consider the context in which it will be used.

Answer (score 1):

I endorse much of [@Wyzard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26512340/240490), but it doesn't go far enough. To be clear:

**YES! Identity is optional for real-world objects.**

Even objects that are not truly identical in every way--two potato chips, for example--are for all practical intents and purposes identical. They are identical in use. No one cares about their individuality. There is no naming scheme, no serial numbers, no hash values to distinguish them in any way. Your two erasers or two oysters you just bought at the local raw seafood bar may have some different characteristics, and they have a physics identity (i.e. they can't occupy the same space at the same time), but there is no meaningful way to talk about them other than pointing at them ("this one is bigger than that one!") or describing them ("the blue eraser--no, that other one that looks like it's been slightly used"). Their identity is only transient, and only what individual users assign. Very few people bother naming their erasers or their oysters. ("Go to work, Fred! Erase!" or "Francine was delicious! Bring me another! I shall name her Sally Wellfleet!")

This no-real-identity is true of many manufactured products, such as nails, pieces of lumber, ball bearings, Ibuprofen caplets, or bottles of Ibuprofen. Manufacturers often track cohort identity--the batch number of which they were a part, for example. But that is the finest granularity for which true identity information is created or considered.

Now, this isn't generally true of electronic devices. Even the humblest Ethernet adaptor, Bluetooth transponder, or RFID tag has an elaborate identification system. It has a manufacturer, a model/part number, a serial number, and often a designed identity (device id), There may also be a "current address" like a MAC address or other "I am operating at/as" identity. Many of these pieces of identifying information are available via [reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)). Individual chips that make up the device may us a manufacturing "batch id" system, but the operational device has a more overt individual identity.

But most real-world objects are not electronic transponders, and they have no meaningful identity other than what we assign.

Comment: Not sure if reflection is the correct concept. You're only accessing information, not "examining or modifying the structure and behavior of the program at runtime."

Comment: @LukeWillis Agree. I might call it mere "inspection" or "introspection." But "reflection" is the older, more computer-sciencey term for "examining one's meta-properties at runtime." That term got established before most languages could do it in any meaningful way, and it's the term Wikipedia used to define the concept.

Comment: Understood. I don't think serial numbers, MAC addresses, or the other properties you listed count as *meta-properties* in this context, though.

Comment: @LukeWillis It depends. MAC addresses would probably be considered just "a property" not a "metaproperty." But that's an address, not an id. What about the manufacturer's serial number? Or the manufacturer's name or SNMP PEN? In networking, a lot of those values are surfaced as a matter of course. Less so in other realms. Identifying values like your CPU's globally unique id, or your system's id--they tend to be more deeply held. I don't entirely disagree with your quibble; I'm just saying that the distinctions between primary data, metadata, and paradata are fluid and contextual.